# Unable to add two layers in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am trying to add two simple layers in keras.  Below is my code.

```python
inputLayer = Input(shape=(28,28,1)) 
conv1 = Conv2D(32,(3,3),strides=1, padding="same", activation='relu') (inputLayer)

conv1 = Conv2D(32,(3,3),strides=1, padding="same", activation='relu') (conv1)
conv1 = Conv2D(49,(25,25),strides=1, padding="valid", activation='relu') (conv1)

# Now I would like to add INputLayer and the last conv layer.

flat = Flatten(name='FlattenLayerName')(conv1)
flat1 = Flatten (name = 'flat1')(inputLayer)


m = keras.layers.add([flat, flat1])

flat = Flatten(name='FlattenLayerName') (m)

dense1 = Dense(10,activation='sigmoid') (flat)
model = Model(input=inputLayer, output=dense1)
print model.summary()
```

I m getting blow error.

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myresNet.py", line 37, in <module>
    flat = Flatten(name='FlattenLayerName') (m)
  File "/home/jils/anaconda2/envs/testML/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 414, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "/home/jils/anaconda2/envs/testML/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 327, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(K.ndim(x)))
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer FlattenLayerName: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Comment: There is no need to use flatten in the output of another flatten layers. That's why it errors.

Comment: What is `flat2`?

Comment: @rvinas, you are right. sorry typo error.

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned in the comments, the problem is not when you're adding the two layers, but when you're trying to flatten the resulting layer that is already flat.

Remove this line:

```
flat = Flatten(name='FlattenLayerName') (m)
```